# Ethereum-based permissioned blockchain implementations

Tags: permissioned-chain

I am new to Ethereum. Trying to find what all permissioned blockchains are available at the moment which are among the most popular ones.

I am just trying to avoid spending unnecessary time to explore all kind of permissioned blockchains and try focusing on one which is really popular to provide realistic solutions. If you could share some nice links where I can start my study will be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monax's ErisDB https://monax.io/platform/db/?redirect_from_eris=true

JPMorgan Quorom https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum

And naturally you can run vanilla Ethereum in a private network, making it a permissioned blockchain.